# Why is this array selection causing such a glitchy phenomenon?

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I was loading a image in openGl with the Glaux library when I came across a very strange phenomenon with a array. Some example of what I tried and if they succeeded or not are below. The curFreeId variable is global. The extra variables I created to test with are local to the function.

Since when does this effect the flow of code.

```
    unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
    modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[curFreeId]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[curFreeId]);
```

vs

```
    modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[0]);
```

The first code will not work. The second will. Does anyone have any clue why this happens?

EDIT: Strangely enough, this also works correctly.

```
unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[curFreeId]);
```

and so does this.

```
unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[curFreeId]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[0]);
```

Continuing on with some testing. I came across even more curious results.

This works

```
    unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
    unsigned int curid = 0;
    modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[curid]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[curFreeId]);
```

But this does not...

```
    unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
    unsigned int curid = curFreeId;
    modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[curid]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[curFreeId]);
```

But this does...

```
    unsigned int curFreeId = 0;
    unsigned int curid = curFreeId = 0;
    modStruct->t[ i ].gluId = curFreeId;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTextureList[curid]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureList[curFreeId]);
```

What is the world... Is this some glitch of some sort?

Comment: Post your entire code.  Is your application multithreaded?  Do you ever get inconsistent results when running the same code multiple times?

Comment: And, with what compiler? With/without optimizations? Is it possible to step through the generated assembly code?

Comment: It is likely you had overwrote some unallocated memory somewhere but without more code it is hard to figure out the problem.

Comment: This is the class method for loading in a 3D model format I created. I was triyng to incorporate textures embedded inside the model with paths. If the path is found, then it loads it into opengl and creates the mipmaps for it and then assigns it the id. 

The code is pretty large, so I'll just upload a Rar file containing it.You can find the project file here: http://celestialcoding.com/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=1581.0;attach=1002
Sorry for linking to my site,but it seems easiest to upload the file there since it is also a programming forum. Anyone there might be able to help me as well.

Comment: @Adam There is no multithreading, and I get consistent results with the application.

@jdv Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  With. No, I am not good enough with asm to debug it that way.

@5ound That seems highly unlikely. There is nothing to allocate or unallocate in that part of the code. Even if there was, that would nto explain why passing a 0 in a static variable has a different effect forma  0 constant.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but you should really be using the data type `GLuint` for texture IDs, not `unsigned int`.  If you look in your OpenGL header files, you'll find that `GLuint` is actually defined to be `unsigned long` (!).  If you're on a 64-bit system where `sizeof(int)==4` and `sizeof(long)==8`, then that's your problem.  But, most compilers use `sizeof(long)==4`, so that's why I doubt this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I just went through the entire project looking for all relations to curFreeId. I managed to find a random addition sign someplace.

```
curFreeId++;
```

I hate the simple bugs...

Thanks for your help guys. I managed to fix a few other bugs because of your suggestions.